# How to make flexbox items shrink correctly when in a nested container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I set up a nested flexbox container like so:

```
<div class="container1">
  <div class="grow1">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="grow2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

...and then set the **width** of grow2 such that it is **wider** than container1 then grow2 overflows container1.

I believe this should **not** happen since flex elements are supposed to shrink when they are larger than the flex container.

If I set the **flex-basis** of grow2 then this works as expected.

Please see the following example for a demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/chris00/ot1gjjtk/20/

**Please use Chrome or Firefox for this**

Furthermore, I read that the flexbox spec says that width and flex-basis should have the same effect (when using horizontal layouts) which they clearly don't.

Now I could just use flex-basis instead of width, but... Edge does the same thing for both flex-basis and width, and it does it in the "wrong" way. IE11 does it wrong also (although that appears to have multiple flexbox bugs).
**Please check out the demo with Edge.**

So how is this supposed to work?

Are there bugs in all browsers?

Is flex-basis actually supposed to be different from width (in simple horizontal layouts)?

Or is Edge correct and both width and flex-basis are supposed to overflow the parent container?

Finally, is there a workaround that can fix the overflow for Edge (and even IE11)?

```css
.container1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.grow1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.grow2a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: turquoise;
}

.grow2b {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="grow1">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="grow2a">Working (flex-basis)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="grow1">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="grow2b">Not working (width)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"width and flex-basis should have the same effect"* ...no, they don't and shouldn't. - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width

Comment: That post says: "7.2.3. The flex-basis property - For all values other than auto and content, flex-basis is resolved the same way as width in horizontal writing modes." - but this is not what I am seeing. I know they are different, but they shouldn't be in horizontal calculations.

Comment: *"resolve the same"* not ARE the same. `width` is width...flex-basis is the width unless acted on by `flex-grow/shrink`. A `px` width is  a fixed value..flexbox doesn't (and shouldn't) override that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### The Problem

As far as the spec is concerned, this isn't an issue pertaining to `flex-basis`, `width`, `flex-grow` or `flex`. It's something entirely different.

> [**4.5. Implied Minimum Size of Flex
>   Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto)
>
> To provide a more reasonable default minimum size for flex items, this
>   specification introduces a new `auto` value as the initial value of
>   the `min-width` and `min-height` properties defined in CSS 2.1.

In other words, a flex item, by default, cannot be smaller than the length of its content (essentially, the longest word or fixed-size element).

The item cannot stay within its container (or even render a scroll bar or ellipsis), because its content is not permitted to overflow. The content simply expands the item. This behavior applies to fixed-sizing, as well (such as the `flex-basis: 400px` in your code).

Again, the initial settings are:

- `min-width: auto`, in row-direction
- `min-height: auto`, in column-direction

For a more complete explanation see this post:

- [Why doesn't flex item shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/3597276)

---

### Solution for Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Edge

The standard solution to this problem is simple: override the default.

In your code, add `min-width: 0` to `.grow1`.

That solves the problem in Chrome, Safari, FF and Edge.

```css
.container1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.grow1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 0; /* NEW */
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.grow2a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: turquoise;
}

.grow2b {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="grow1">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="grow2a">Working (flex-basis)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="grow1">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="grow2b">Not working (width)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/ot1gjjtk/21/)

---

### Solution for IE11

In IE11, contrary to spec guidance, the flex `min-width` / `min-height` default values are already `0`, yet the flex item still breaks out.

The defaults are `0` because when the flexbox spec was first released, the `min-*` properties did not deviate from the [CSS 2.1 initial values](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#min-max-widths), which are `0`.

Later, after browsers had completed their implementations, the flex `min-*` values were updated to `auto`. Chrome, Safari, FF and Edge made the update. IE11 did not.

The reason the flex items break out in IE11 relates to another issue: *the browser wants an explicit width on the container*

In your code, add `flex-basis: 100%` to `.grow1`.

More details here:

- [Why IE11 doesn't wrap the text in flexbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35111090/3597276)
- [flexbox flex-basis: 0px in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40052987/3597276)

```css
.container1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.grow1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  flex-basis: 100%; /* NEW */
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.grow2a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: turquoise;
}

.grow2b {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="grow1">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="grow2a">Working (flex-basis)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="grow1">
    <div class="container2">
      <div class="grow2b">Not working (width)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**revised fiddle 2 (IE11)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ot1gjjtk/22/)

---

### More Browser Discrepancies

Evidence appears to exist (in this question and other examples I've seen) that Webkit-based browsers are no longer honoring the `auto` default defined in the spec.

Moreover, the adherence to the `auto` standard may vary based on which property is used for sizing: `flex-basis` vs. `width` / `height`

As discussed in the following post, these properties should render the same way.

- [What are the differences between flex-basis and width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34352140/3597276)

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. I had actually worked out the min-width:0 part but it's interesting to read your explanation of how this fits into the spec. Also interesting that width & flex-basis are not the problem. Your fix for IE11 is inspired! I had tried a similar fix with width:100% but without any joy. Thanks again.