# Flexbox column, child goes out of bound in Edge

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a flex-box container and a child in it, The child should fill the container but should not go out of bound.

The following CSS works fine on all browsers except for Edge, the content goes out of bound

```
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   height: 200px;
}

.child {
   flex: 1;
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz reproduction](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nndbgh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css), please try it on Chrome and Edge to see the difference.

Why isn't `flex: 1` working on Edge when flex-box is supported?

> **P.S.** Using `height: 100%` will fix it, but another issue occurs (in Edge only), the horizontal scrollbar gets pushed down and disappears.

**Chrome screenshot (works properly)**

[image]

**Edge screenshot (horizontal scrollbar is pushed down when it should not)**

[image]

This demo uses `height: 100%`

https://murhafsousli.github.io/ngx-scrollbar/

Comment: Can you reproduce this without ngx-scrollbars?

Comment: @NateWhittaker I already added a reproduction https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nndbgh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to why ngx-scrollbar is mentioned in the question then?

Comment: Because it is my use case, so I don't get `height: 100%` as a fix, you never mind

Comment: Spent more time on this than I would have liked but the fix is to add `min-height: 0` to `.ng-scrollbar-y-layout`.  You can read more about the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934648/how-to-make-flexbox-items-shrink-correctly-when-in-a-nested-container).

Comment: @StevenB. it WORKED! I spent 2 days on this and couldn't figure it out! Thanks a lot